# Migration from existing Java EE project to maven without changing directory layout

Tags: maven, ant, directory-structure, rails-migrations

I have seen many questions concerning this issue, but I'm new to this topic and I have to convert previously written project (standard, Eclipse Java EE project) into Maven.

My first problem is that I'm completely new to Maven. Second - I can't change the directory layout. And third - I'm running out of time.

Some of topics I've read covered few of my questions, but I need it clearer.

I have 3 modules connected with each other: 
* Main one with catalogues: .settings, db-schema, EarContent, 
* EJB with .settings, bin, build, ejbModule
* WEB with .settings, build, src, WebContent.

As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong) there is just one 'mapping' when I have single catalogue with source code and it looks like this:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>ejbModule</sourceDirectory>
    ...
```

But what if I have two catalogues? I mean the WEB module - src and WebContent.
What else do I need to change if don't use standard directory layout?
What with the main module with EarContent? - There is no source code, but there is an -ds.xml file which (I guess) I have to put somewhere.
In main POM.xml I know that I have to add  tags, but is there anything else I should do?

Sorry for (maybe) not precise and wide questions, but I've started today and I have to do it fast. So far I've found Sonatype site and managed to get one of their pdfs, but I'm reading it quite too slow and need 'some' help doing it. I've also downloaded the archetype for nexus repository and I'm trying to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use add-source goal of [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).